# Migration module not recognized as a migration at runtime by Ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

So I’m doing migrations at runtime and Ecto is complaining that a module I pass it to execute a migration is not a migration.

I think it has something to do with use being lazy?

Check to see if the module has a function called `__migration__/0`

```
function_exported?(Pos.Repo.Migrations.CreateUsersAuthTables, :__migration__, 0)
false
```

Sure enough it says it doesn’t exist.

Now I use `__info__(:functions)` to see what functions the module does export and…

```
Pos.Repo.Migrations.CreateUsersAuthTables.__info__(:functions)
[__migration__: 0, change: 0]
```

Ok, odd…

Checking again:

```
function_exported?(Pos.Repo.Migrations.CreateUsersAuthTables, :__migration__, 0)
true
```

What’s going on here? Is `use` lazily evaluated or something? How come my migration modules don't have `__migration__/0` functions on them until I check them with `__info__/0`?

Answer (score 1):

Migrations are stored in *elixir script* files (having `.exs` extension.) These files are **not** compiled by `mix` by default.

One option you have is to compile scripts explicitly or change the extension to `.ex` so that `mix` compiles those by default (not recommended.)

Another one would be to not reinvent a wheel and use the [`Ecto.Migrator`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Migrator.html#migrations/1) tool provided by `ecto_sql`.

Comment: This is false, since these migrations are done at runtime they are stored in `.ex` files. This is stated in the question.

Comment: I am using the `Ecto.Migrator` tool, that is the code that initially told me that my module was not a migration module.

Comment: Please include this answer as a comment instead as it is does not address the question asked.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with compiling migrations and doing them at runtime. There are many situations where you might want to do that, in my case it's for creating prefixed tables for multi tenency when a tenant account is created. https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/multi-tenancy-with-query-prefixes.html

Comment: It surely addresses a question. _“Is `use` lazily evaluated or something?”_ shows you barely understand how [tag:elixir] compiler ever works, that’s why I started the explanation from a difference between `.exs` and `.ex`. `require` cannot ever change anything, the issue might be induced, but in this case the information provided in the OP is not sufficient.

Comment: `require` could have possibly affected the behavior id `__migration__/0` were an injected macro, but [it’s a function](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto_sql/blob/v3.7.1/lib/ecto/migration.ex#L427-L432) which, as you can see from the source code, gets injected _after_ module compilation.

Answer (score -2):

I needed to `require` the migration modules in the module where I was checking for the macro function on them in order to use their macros.

https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html#require

Comment: Please avoid posting answers when you are uncertain.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Can you explain why a compiled module that has `use Ecto.Migration` returns `false` when `function_exported?(MigrationModuleName, :__migration__, 0)` is called? And then returns `true` after `__info__/1` is called?

Comment: Not without any additional info. [`Kernel.function_exported?/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#function_exported?/3) requires the module to be already _loaded_. Do you call the above from [tag:elixir-iex]? What happens if one calls `Code.ensure_loaded(Pos.Repo.Migrations.CreateUsersAuthTables)`? What are `elixirc_paths` setting in `mix.exs`?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin `iex -S mix phx.server`, also `mix phx.server` Result is: `{:module, Pos.Repo.Migrations.CreateUsersAuthTables}` Then when I use it with the Migrator: `(Ecto.MigrationError) module Pos.Repo.Migrations.CreateStores is not an Ecto.Migration`

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin  `defp elixirc_paths(_), do: ["lib"]`, I moved the runtime migrations from `/priv` to `/lib/repo/migrations`

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin `Code.ensure_loaded/1` has the same effect as `__info__/1` on causing `function_exported?/3` to return true where without the call to either of those functions it was false.